# Parse sdk android app not loading content in 5.0

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-5.0-lollipop

I have integrated parse sdk in my android app and tested it on android 5.0 on a real device. The problem is that initially the app does not display any content it is completely blank, but after few hours the app starts functioning normally with push notifications. Has anyone faced this issue before or can anyone tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: *Has anyone faced this issue before ?* is not a valid question on StackOverflow ... as answer for such question is simple "yes" or "no" :)

Comment: @selvin, if anyone had faced this situation they would reply yes and would give a solution, if anyone had not faced this problem, they would not answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i finally have got the solution to this problem. If you have been using parse example from foamyguy from githhub you would have a blank activity in android 5.0 when you run it for the first time. The solution is just go to **ParseApplication.java** and comment the line which says

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

And run it, it will work, if your application crashes, then use this line

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveEventually();
```

This will completely fix your application.